# How to read geometry from gpkg?

Tags: sqlite, geopackage

I have a gpkg file. I trying to open it with `spatial_lite gui` and cast geometry to GML.

```
select AsGML(geom) from MyTable
```

but i got `null`. I tried another functions `AsText(), AsWKT(), st_asText()...` but anyway i got null. BTW function ST_GeometryType(geom) returns `LINESTRING`, but other functions don't work.
My final goal is to cast geometry from gpkg to GML on c#. But it's looks impossible because I cannot even select geometry in  `spatial_lite gui`.
Do I use wrong queries? What can be wrong here?

Comment: are there any rows in your table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The binary format for geometry in GeoPackages is not compatible with the format used in Spatialite. That's (partly) why GDAL has separate drivers.

When I start the Spatialite GUI it helpfully displays this:

[image]

And that means instead of querying the table `d` I can query `vgpkg_d` and the Spatialite geometry functions will work:

[image]

If I query from the original table I get NULL, like you.

[image]

If your spatialite GUI doesn't show that message or create the virtual tables then you need to upgrade or install some other components.

Comment: Is it warped tables created by `spatialite_gui` right? So they not conteins in original `gpkg` file? Is it means that i can not to call them from c# using just a `sqlite` provider?

Comment: In the end i just added GDAL to project.